# how to add button n times on xamarin

Tags: xamarin

First of all i have seen few topics about that but didnt helped i typed thoose in xamarin.

i add a button in that way

```
Button desk = new Button
        {
            Text = desknumber.ToString(),
            Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large),
            BorderWidth = 1,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
```

so i have to run this command in loop or in a method like that

```
public void masaekle(int masasayisi)
    {

        Button desknumber = new Button
        {
            Text = masasayisi.ToString(),
            Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large),
            BorderWidth = 1,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };

        this.Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {

                desknumber,

            }
        };
```

it doesnt work in any variable type so i stuck here i cant give a variable name to the button

Comment: When you say "It does not work" what is really happening to your code/app?

Comment: only 1 button shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time you assign `Content` it overwrites what is already there

```
var sl = new StackLayout();

// some loop conditions
for(;;)
{
  var button = new Button { ... };
  sl.Children.Add(button);
}

this.Content = sl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i have already tried that and i wrote c# on xamarin

Comment: This is not the same as the code you posted.  The code you posted included creates a new StackLayout for every button

Comment: Hey do you have any idea about how can i place thoose buttons next to next i have to fill the screen

Comment: use a horizontal StackLayout

Comment: sir i did but only 6 buttons fits on screen others are doesnt fit to screen

Comment: Then make the buttons smaller?  If you have a new problem then you should post a new question.